# P-overlayPanel is giving me white corners

Tags: css, sass, themes, overlay, primeng

When I click on my overlay panel I get these white corners [Overlaypanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xloTP.png), I have tried adjusting the width and height and the border radius but nothing seems to work. this is my SCSS:

```html
::ng-deep #topbar {
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid rgba(var(--support-02-color-rgb), 0.3);
  .p-toolbar {
    padding: 0.5rem 0rem 0.35rem;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0rem;
    background: white;
  }
}

.find-patron-button {
  cursor: pointer;

  .find-patron-button-label {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;

    color: #707070;
  }

  button {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;

    background: #24135F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0.625rem;
  }
}
```